# Possible to pin NVDA's screen reading to one application?

Tags: ebook, screen-reader

NV Access's screen reader does the job of reading e-books reasonably well; though, in my case I'd like to use it while multi-tasking. For example, I'd like it to continue reading from an e-book application or web article while I switch away to do some monotonous data entry or organizational work.

So is it possible to pin the reader to an application?

(Ideally I'd like to avoid the overhead of full-blown VM to isolate the reader and desired content.)

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd like for NV Access to keep reading aloud from an e-book when you switch to using other applications? How does it work now? If you switch to another application, does NV Access stop reading from the e-book and start reading from what you switched to instead?

Comment: Now it stops reading the content and switches to reading whatever the mouse focuses on.